# React auto-suggest issue with search

Tags: reactjs, node.js, autocomplete

I am building functionality in which I am taking 3 inputs from user showing results based on matching input from JSON. I am using react-autocomplete from input suggestions.
Now, the issues are:

1. I am typing in input 1 and selecting something it is filling up input 2 first followed by input 3 and input 1 at the end.
2. My search shouldn't allow a single-character search rather than show only matching phrases.
3. Shouldn't allow duplicate selection.

Any luck is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest';
const [searchTerms, setSearchTerms] = useState(['', '', '']);
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState({});

  const getSuggestions = (value) => {
  if (value !== undefined && value.trim() !== '') {
    const inputValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();
    const allJobs = Object.values(courseData).flatMap(category => category.flatMap(subCategory => subCategory.jobRoles));
    
    // Check for exact matches first
    const exactMatches = allJobs.filter(job => job.toLowerCase() === inputValue);

    // If no exact matches, look for partial matches (case-insensitive)
    const partialMatches = allJobs.filter(job => job.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue));
    
    return exactMatches.length > 0 ? exactMatches : partialMatches;
  }
  return [];
};

  const onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
    setSuggestions(getSuggestions(value));
  };

  const onSuggestionSelected = (event, { suggestionValue }) => {
    const updatedTerms = [...searchTerms];
    const selectedInputIndex = searchTerms.findIndex(term => term === suggestionValue);

    if (selectedInputIndex !== -1) {
      // If the suggestion is already in one of the input fields, don't populate it again
      return;
    }

    const emptyIndex = updatedTerms.findIndex(term => term === '');
    if (emptyIndex !== -1) {
      updatedTerms[emptyIndex] = suggestionValue;
      setSearchTerms(updatedTerms);
    }
  };

  const inputProps = (index) => ({
    placeholder: `Search term ${index + 1}`,
    value: searchTerms[index],
    onChange: (e, { newValue }) => {
      const updatedTerms = [...searchTerms];
      updatedTerms[index] = newValue;
      setSearchTerms(updatedTerms);
    },
  });

  const renderSuggestion = (suggestion) => (
    <div>
      {suggestion}
    </div>
  );

  const handleSearch = () => {
    // Remove empty search terms
    const nonEmptySearchTerms = searchTerms.filter(term => term !== undefined && term.trim() !== '');

    if (nonEmptySearchTerms.length > 0) {
      // Remove duplicates
      const uniqueSearchTerms = [...new Set(nonEmptySearchTerms)];

      // Your search logic
      const filteredData = Object.keys(courseData).reduce((acc, category) => {
        const filteredSubCategories = courseData[category].filter(subCategory => {
          return uniqueSearchTerms.some(term => subCategory.jobRoles.some(role => role.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())));
        });

        if (filteredSubCategories.length > 0) {
          acc[category] = filteredSubCategories;
        }

        return acc;
      }, {});

      setSearchResults(filteredData);
    } else {
      // Handle empty search
      alert('Please enter at least one search term');
    }
  };
```

and these are the inputs on view.

```
<div>
      <div>
        {searchTerms.map((term, index) => (
          <Autosuggest
            key={index}
            suggestions={suggestions}
            onSuggestionsFetchRequested={onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
            onSuggestionSelected={(event, { suggestionValue }) => onSuggestionSelected(event, { suggestionValue })}
            getSuggestionValue={(suggestion) => suggestion}
            renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
            inputProps={inputProps(index)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleSearch}>Search</button>

      {Object.keys(searchResults).map((category, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <h3>{category}</h3>
          <ul>
            {searchResults[category].map((subCategory, subIndex) => (
              <li key={subIndex}>{subCategory.name}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```